# How to get route parameter inside template using ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have code like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('managementPanels-show', {
    url: '/management-panels/show/:id',
    template: '<mp-show></mp-show>',
    data: {},
    resolve: {}
  });
```

how can I add :id to the template?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot directly access the `:id` in template. You need to inject the `$stateParams` service in your controller and expose the `:id` property on controller `$scope`

```
.controller('YourController', function ($scope, $stateParams){
   $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
})
```

In your template now you can access id as:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('managementPanels-show', {
    url: '/management-panels/show/:id',
    template: '<mp-show>{{id}}</mp-show>',
    controller: 'YourController',
    data: {},
    resolve: {}
  });
```

Comment: I just add an additional info as I lost a an hour on it: if you have to pass parameter to your component, you must not use {{}}. Eg. ``<mp-show param="id"></mp-show>``. Not how I passed the 'id'.

Answer (score 3):

I Just want to integrate the [good answer from Aditya](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38265863/752004), as I spend one hour to this issue:

if you have to pass the 'id' as a "<" parameter to your component, you must not use curly braces:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('managementPanels-show', {
  url: '/management-panels/show/:id',
  template: '<mp-show param="id">{{id}}</mp-show>',
  controller: function ($scope, $stateParams){ $scope.id = $stateParams.id; },
  data: {},
  resolve: {}
});
```

Note the 'id' passed to "<" 'param' without curly braces. On the other side, "@" parameters remains as param="{{id}}".

Also note: I wrote the controller directly into the state definition, just for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: You mean `param="id"` it depend on how you have scope or binding in mp-show. if it's `"@"` it should be `param="{{id}}"` and if it's `"="` then it should be `param="id"`. Also the question was about `$stateParams.id;` (that was the answer)

Comment: @jcubic you're right! I'm going to update the answer

Answer (score 3):

If you plan to integrate $state and $stateParams often in your templates, it might be useful to add it assign it to $scope or $rootScope. See the following example from the Docs:

```
angular.module("myApp").run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
});
```

Now you can interpolate data values on $scope and $rootScope using Angular's double curly bracket notation.

**Config:**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('content', {
        url: "/",
        data: {
            title: 'test'
        }
    })
```

**Template:**

```
{{ $state.current.data.title }}
```

Source: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/quick-reference#note-about-using-state-within-a-template

Answer (score 1):

Use $stateParams. Read about it [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)

```
console.log($stateParams.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use a custom template and injected parameters is to use `templateProvider`:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('managementPanels-show', {
    url: '/management-panels/show/:id',
    templateProvider: function($stateParams){ return '<mp-show>' + $stateParams.id + '</mp-show>'; },
    data: {},
    resolve: {}
  });
```

All injectables are available, not just `$stateParams`.
It is important to remember though, that the `templateProvider` returns a `template`, and NOT a `templateUrl`!

---

If it is desired to use parameters with a `templateUrl`, it also takes in a function with only parameter as `$stateParams`(shame):

```
$stateProvider
  .state('managementPanels-show', {
    url: '/management-panels/show/:id',
    templateUrl: function($stateParams){ return 'templates/mytemplate/' + $stateParams.id; },
    data: {},
    resolve: {}
  });
```